# how to save values in core data in swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I have to apply checkmarks on the contacts received by using address book. When I'm selecting contacts then checkmarks appears but after scrolling it disappears. Secondly, I have to save these selected contacts into core data. Just have a look at that and tell me what I'm doing wrong.What Wrong i'am doing with Core Data.

Comment: I don't see any code involving CoreData.

Comment: actually firstly m trying to apply checkmarks

Comment: checkmarks are appearing...if i select section 1 rows then it automatically slects other section rows....i have no idea whty it is happening

Comment: if u r having any idea about it then plz tell me....nd how i can save these checkmarks in core data??

Comment: pnks I have taken 2 variables such as section and keys and wrote the code below.Please give it a try.

Comment: okay i will.....actually m trying to create a group....nd in that group i have to add selected contacts....thats what i needed

Comment: plzz tell me how to display checkmarks correctlty

Answer (score 1):

```
 class LogItem: NSManagedObject {
        @NSManaged var section: String
        @NSManaged var keys: String
    }
```

Now declare the object of this class like this:

```
let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("LogItem", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as! LogItem

    newItem.section = "section Title"
    newItem.keys = "keys text"
}
```

You can fetch the data as follows:

```
        //  request using the LogItem entity
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "LogItem")

        // Execute the fetch request, and cast the results to an array of LogItem objects
        if let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [LogItem] {

println(fetchResults[0].section)     // prints "section title"
println(fetchResults[0].key)  // prints key text
    }
```

> Please Make sure that core data is able to save only properties.
>
> According to apple documentation, “The Core Data framework provides
>   generalized and automated solutions to common tasks associated with
>   object life-cycle and object graph management, including persistence.”

Comment: i need to add value from checkmarks selected....how to do it with core data..../..actually m new to ios and swift...so have no idea about it.....plzz tell me if u can

Comment: you van see that I have added the `newItem` Object. Just declare the parameters there and pass it along for `NSEntityDescription`. Just make sure there are declared  NSObject. Hope it helps.

Comment: let me know if you need any other help and do close the question once done! Glad to help

Comment: plzzz have a look at my did select method....whats wrong m doing there....checkmarks are not working properly...

Answer (score 0):

First, you add CoreData, then go to AppDelegate and you will see this code:

```
 lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
     let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model_data")
     container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
         if let error = error as NSError? {
             fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
         }
     })
     return container
 }()
```

In: let container . . . you see (name: "Model_data")
This name needs to be same as your model file name.

Then go to your View Controller and add:

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let newItem = Item(context: self.context)
```

Item is an entity from your model object.

add newItem to an array like:

```
self.itemArray.append(newItem)
```

Then, add next logic:

```
 fileprivate func saveContext() {
     do {
         try context.save()
         // if it is table view, you need to reload here. tableView.reloadData()
     } catch {
         print("Failed to with error: \(error)")
     }
 }
```

if loading is problem add this logic:

```
fileprivate func loadContext() {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
    do {
        itemModel = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print("Error in request: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Save and load.